# how to change the format of heatmap data to percentage?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to change the format of heatmap highchart data, but i am getting error while adding formatter (Property 'point' does not exist on type '{ enabled: boolean; formatter: () => any; }'.), below is my code:

```
collection = [
    {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 428
    },
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0.023364
    },
    {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0.023364
    },
    {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 11,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 12,
        "y": 0,
        "value": 0
    }
]

chartOptions = {
        lang: {
          noData: 'No data found',
        },
        noData: {
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '15px',
          },
        },
        chart: {
          type: 'heatmap',
          events: {
            load: function () {
              const chart = this;
            },
          },
        },
        title: {
          text: null,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        xAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'R-Score',
          },
          categories: x_data,
          opposite: true,
          tickWidth: 0,
        },

        legend: {
          visible: true,
        },

        yAxis: [
          {
            height: '80%',
            categories: Object.keys(y_data),
            title: {
              align: 'high',
              offset: 0,
              text: 'F-Score',
              rotation: 0,
              y: -10,
            },
            reversed: true,
          },
          {
            height: '20%',
            top: '80%',
            title: null,
          },
          {
            height: '20%',
            top: '80%',
            linkedTo: 2,
            title: null,
            offset: 0,
          },
        ],
        colorAxis: [
          {
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false,
            showInLegend: true,
          },
        ],

        plotOptions: {
          heatmap: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: '#000000',
            },
          },
          series: {
            events: {
              click: (event: any) => this.openPopup(event),
            },
          },
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: '',
            type: 'heatmap',
            borderWidth: 1,
            yAxis: 0,
            data: (function () {
              collection.forEach(function (p: any) {
                if (p.x >= 0) {
                  var basePoint = collection.find(
                    (p_: any) => p_.x === 0 && p_.y === p.y
                  );
                  p.percentValue = p.value;
                  p.value = p.value * basePoint.value;
                }
              });
              return collection;
            })(),
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              formatter: function():any {
                return this.point.percentValue ? this.point.percentValue * 100 + "%" : this.point.value;
              }
            },

          },
        ],
      };
```

Please help me on how can i add this percent value in my heatmap. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own type following the wrapper documentation tips:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-yyy

or cast `this.point` to `any`.

```
 dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter(): any {
        return (this.point as any).percentValue
          ? (this.point as any).percentValue * 100 + '%'
          : this.point.value;
      }
    }
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-4ec4eu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts%3AL89